# My character won't move even if i set the velocity.y += gravity

Tags: gdscript

```
extends CharacterBody2D


var gravity = 80
var speed = 32
var player = null


func _ready():
    $AnimationPlayer.play("idle")
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    move_character()
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = gravity
func move_character():
    
    if player == null:
        return
    if player:
        if (player.position.x - position.x) > 30 or (player.position.x - position.x) < -30 :
            position.x += (player.position.x - position.x)/60
            
        
        
    if (player.position.x - position.x) < 0:
        $Sprite2D.flip_h = true
    else:
        $Sprite2D.flip_h = false
    move_and_slide()


func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):
    player = body
   

func _on_area_2d_body_exited():
    player = null
```

i tried to change the place of the velocity.y += gravity but nothing worked i don't know whats influencing velocity.y into not working, can some one help me?

Comment: try to use some of the examples from the tutorials in docs. If even these examples wont work (I doubt that), report is as a bug in documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_character_body_2d.html